# Trouble binding a BindingList to ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

In the app I'm working on, I need to maintain a list of Projects which are currently loaded, and display the names of each one in a ListBox (okay, multiple ListBoxes, but that's neither here nor there).

```
class Project
{
    public String Name;

    // Etc. etc...
}
```

I've got a BindingList object which contains all of the loaded Projects, and am binding it to my ListBox(es).

```
private BindingList<Project> project_list = new BindingList<Project>();
private ListBox project_listbox;

private void setList()
{
    project_listbox.DisplayMember = "Name";
    project_listbox.ValueMember = "Name";
    project_listbox.DataSource = project_list;
}
```

However when I do this, all that gets displayed in `project_listbox` is a set of the class names for the Project.  Am I missing something here?  Every reference that I could find regarding binding Lists to a ListBox uses a very similar setup.

Comment: By default the listbox will call ToString() on your class for a display value.  You could have just as easily implemented public Override ToString() and returned Name as the string result.

Comment: This is a bad solution if you want a property to be the ValueMember, though :) You'd still need to make that one {get; private set}. If not, ValueMember won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make the properties readable :)

```
class Project
{
    public string Name {get; private set;}

    // Etc. etc...
}
```

Now it should work. I just tested it.

<strike>This should work as well:</strike>

```
public readonly string Name;
```

As I have been pointed out. Putting "readonly" doesn't work. I just tested and verified it myself.

Comment: +1 for the property, but forget the readonly field. DisplayMember has to be the name of a property.

Comment: Thanks.  This works, though I'm unclear as to why this is functionally different than what I had previously.  Does the ValueMember property only work when the `set` is private?

Comment: No no, just a habit :) You normally wouldn't want other classes to simply to set your properties to whatever the feel like. It is practically "readonly" I have applied to the property.

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, note that if you want to search on or sort the BindingList, you will need to implement it and add this functionality

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms993236.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A possible issue that one might have is that new items are not inserted to the BindingList but to its parent List